# how to get the category Id pass to the list of products with vue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

When you click Categories, you get the `category_id`, pass to the list of products, and display the products by category? go to the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhouyulong/2m13bhne/).

How to achieve it? Like the picture below：

This Apple category：

[image]

This Xiaomi category：

[image]

#### Look at the javascropt file:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    active: 0,
    category: [{
      category_id: "1",
      category_name: "Apple"
    }, {
      categoryid: "2",
      category_name: "Xiaomi"
    }],
    products: [

      {
        category_id: "1",
        goods_name: "iphone6s",
      }, {
        category_id: "1",
        goods_name: "macbook pro"
      }, {
        category_id: "2",
        goods_name: "hongmi5 Plus"
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle(i, v) {
      this.active = i
      this.currentView = v
    }
  }


})
```

CSS file:

```
.active {
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

ul li {
  padding: 0 15px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}
```

HTML file:

```
<div id="app">

  <ul>
    <li @click="toggle($index,item.category_name)" v-for="item in category" :class="{active: active == $index}">{{ item.category_name }}</li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <div class="layui-tab-content">
    <div class="layui-tab-item" v-for="item in products"> {{item.goods_name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've changed your [tag:java] tag to a [tag:javascript] tag. Please understand that these are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help. Since I know absolutely nothing about Javascript, this is about all that I can do for you except to wish you well and hope that you get a decent answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a computed categoryProducts which filter the products array by category_id, see the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2m13bhne/3/).

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentView: 'child1',
    active: '1',
    category: [{
      category_id: "1",
      category_name: "Apple"
    }, {
      category_id: "2",
      category_name: "Xiaomi"
    }],
    products: [
      {
        category_id: "1",
        goods_name: "iphone6s",
      }, {
        category_id: "1",
        goods_name: "macbook pro"
      }, {
        category_id: "2",
        goods_name: "hongmi5 Plus"
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    categoryProducts () {
        let that = this
        return this.products.filter(p => p.category_id === that.active)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle(i, v) {
      this.active = i
      console.log(i)
      //this.currentView = v
    }
  }


})
```